# Output data to a String in another class in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I am currently having trouble pulling certain values from a list.  I want to print `theData` to a String in another class called `Card` and I am not sure how to go about this:

```
private List<FootballPlayer> getData() {
    List<FootballPlayer> theData = new ArrayList<FootballPlayer>();
    // create a Scanner and grab the data . . .
    Scanner scanner = null;
    String dataPath = dbLocation + File.separator + "text" + File.separator + "players.db";
    String imagePath = dbLocation + File.separator + "images";
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new File(dataPath));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) { 
        System.out.println(fnf.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // scan player.db file line-by-line
    scanner.useDelimiter("\n");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String line = scanner.next().trim();
       // trim used to trim for new line
        String[] bits = line.split(":");
        String t = bits[0];                    // title
        String imgFileName = bits[1];          // image file name
        int pa = Integer.parseInt(bits[2]);     // pace
        int sh = Integer.parseInt(bits[3]);     // shooting
        int dr = Integer.parseInt(bits[4]);    // dribbling
        int ph = Integer.parseInt(bits[5]);    // physical
        // create the image
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(imagePath + File.separator +  imgFileName);
      // Create the business object
       FootballPlayer player = new FootballPlayer(t, img, pa, sh, dr, ph);
      // add it to the list ... simple as ...
      theData.add(player);
}
  scanner.close(); 
  return theData;
```

}

My players.db currently looks like this if it helps:

```
Pique:DFPique.png:66:60:54:76
Ramos:DFRamos.png:79:66:60:82
Maldini:LEGMaldini.png:86:67:56:80
Pele:LEGPele.png:95:94:89:73
DiMaria:MFDiMaria.png:90:87:79:71
Neymar:MFNeymar.png:90:92:80:58
Berahino:STBerahino.png:81:70:69:55
Ronaldo:STRonaldo.png:98:99:99:89
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your problem is maybe in the other class if you want to output the contents in the Array list you have to iterate over it and your Football player needs a to string Method you could use this object is you class which have your getdata method you posted

```
for(FootballPlayer each: object.getData())
System.out.println(each.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `FootballPlayer` has a `toString` method, if you wish to be concise:

```
Arrays.toString(theData.toArray());
```

Comment: Good answer, but imperative for `FootballPlayer` to have `toString` overridden.